# What is $dW^a_t dW^b_t$ for two various Wiener processes?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I need to **simplify** $dW^a_t dW^b_t$ where $W^a_t$ and $W^b_t$ are two **different** Wiener processes.
If I had only one process $W_t$, I could use the following properties:

$$ (dt)^2 = 0 \\ dt \text{ } dW_t = 0 \\ (dW_t)^2 = dt$$

Is it possible to do something similar with $dW^a_t dW^b_t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't have anything. But like, if you have the independence of two processes, the product is necessarily zero.

Comment: Can you give an intuitive explanation why it's zero if these two events are independent?

Comment: Hmm. You can see it heuristically like why you feel that $dW_tdW_t=dt$. It is because , roughly speaking,   dW_t d_Wt represents some thing like $( W_{t}-W_{s})^2$ with $t,s$ which are "close". And in a long sum, those square converge to some thing like $dt$.

Comment: That is: $ \sum_{n=1}^{N} (W_{a_{n}}-W_{a_{n-1}})^2 \rightarrow t$ for ${ a_0<...<a_N }$ is a partition of $[0,t]$

Comment: Same goes for $dW^b_tdW^a_t$ , it represents something like $(W^b_{t}-W_s^b) (W^a_{t}-W_s^a)$ and the respective sum for this object tends to zero.

Comment: In sum, vaguely speaking, $dW_tdW_t$ is a quantity that measures the correlation of the  fluctation of $(W_t)$ in second order. When $(W^b_t), (W^a_t)$ are independent, there correlation is zero ( in heuristical sense).

Comment: Hope this help.